# Network is not working

Tags: networking, wireless

I have updated to the new version of Ubuntu. My network doesn't work, even the wireless button doesn't work anymore - neither does it work with ethernet cable.

The version before worked properly can someone help me?

Comment: Can you be more specific please: Which new version of Ubuntu, what did you do to solve the problem? What's in the file /etc/interfaces/networking? Do you have any other information that might be useful to solve your problem? Please edit your question and add the info.

Comment: It would really help  if you provided output of at least these three commands in terminal: `sudo lshw -c network` (wireless card model and driver ), `lsmod` (list of loaded modules), OR `nmcli dev  list`. You can copy them into your question or to paste.ubuntu.com and place link here. My guess is that the newer kernel that came with your upgrade has faulty module or isn't loading properly. Try booting you computer and going to "Advanced Options for Ubuntu" on the bootloader screen, then select any other kernel.